# Link to fat Static Library inside Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, static-libraries, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I’m trying to build a Swift Package that wraps a fat static library written in C: *libndi_advanced_ios.a* from [NewTek's Apple Advanced NDI SDK](https://www.ndi.tv/sdk/#download).

I am having trouble linking the pre-compiled library (only headers files and .a binary package is available) to my Swift Package. I have done a lot of research and tried different solutions, but none of them worked. Here is a quick list:

- Cannot [bundle in an XCFramework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages) because *libndi_advanced_ios.a* supports multiple platforms (arm_v7, i386, x86_64, arm64) and `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` return the error `binaries with multiple platforms are not supported` (this solution is discussed on [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/packaging-static-library-in-spm-package-for-ios-executable/41245/2) too);
- Using `.linkedLibrary` in `targets` as suggested on [SPM Documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#requiring-system-libraries) (that is [outdated](https://forums.swift.org/t/problem-with-new-package-manager-system-library-targets/16358/9)) gives the warning `system packages are deprecated; use system library targets instead`, and I don’t even remember if it builds successfully;
- Playing around with different flags and settings (like `linkerSettings`) has not been successful. Maybe I just missed the right combination.

I can link dozens of Stackoverflow's questions and other posts that didn’t help, but it will be useless ([a](https://forums.swift.org/t/packaging-a-static-c-libraries-in-swift-package-manager/28323), [b](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-manage-a-custom-module-modulemap-for-a-package/38165), [c](https://rderik.com/blog/making-a-c-library-available-in-swift-using-the-swift-package/)).

At the moment I have this configuration:

[image: project structure with module.modulemap]

With `Package.swift` that contains the following code:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "swift-ndi",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "swift-ndi",
            targets: ["swift-ndi"])
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "CiOSNDI", path: "Libraries"),
        .target(
            name: "swift-ndi",
            dependencies: ["CiOSNDI"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "swift-ndiTests",
            dependencies: ["swift-ndi"]),
    ]
    
)
```

You can find the whole project at [alessionossa/swift-ndi](https://github.com/alessionossa/swift-ndi).
The only result at the moment are some warnings and the module CiOSNDI do not build:

[image: errors and warnings]

I tried also `.systemLibrary(name: "CiOSNDI", path: "Libraries/"),` with this configuration: [alessionossa/swift-ndi/tree/systemLibrary](https://github.com/alessionossa/swift-ndi/tree/systemLibrary); but I get these errors:
[image: errors and warnings 2]

**NOTE**

`NDI_include` is actually an alias/symbolic link to `/Library/NDI Advanced SDK for Apple/include`, while `NDI_iOS_lib` points to `/Library/NDI Advanced SDK for Apple/lib/iOS`.

I always cleaned build folder after changes to `Package.swift`.

**UPDATE 10/01/2022**: *libndi_advanced_ios.a* requires *libc++.tbd*. That can be easy linked in an app in **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries**, but I don’t know how to link in a Swift Package.

Comment: It looks like you can link in a Swift Package using the [`linkerSettings`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/target/3112791-linkersettings) target parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also needed to add the NDI SDK as a Swift package dependency in my app.

I found a couple of approaches that worked:

You can create an XCFramework bundle by extracting a thin arm64 library from the universal library:

```
lipo "/Library/NDI SDK for Apple/lib/iOS/libndi_ios.a" -thin arm64 -output "$STAGING_DIRECTORY/libndi.a"
```

Then create an XCFramework bundle:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library "$STAGING_DIRECTORY/libndi.a" -headers "/Library/NDI SDK for Apple/include" -output "$STAGING_DIRECTORY/Clibndi.xcframework"
```

I ended up not using this approach because hosting the XCFramework as a downloadable binary release on GitHub required me to make my repo public (see [this issue](https://forums.swift.org/t/spm-support-basic-auth-for-non-git-binary-dependency-hosts/37878)).

Instead I am using a system library target, in my Package.swift:

```swift
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "WrapperLibrary",
            dependencies: ["Clibndi"], 
            linkerSettings: [
                .linkedFramework("Accelerate"),
                .linkedFramework("VideoToolbox"),
                .linkedLibrary("c++")
            ]),
        .systemLibrary(name: "Clibndi")
    ]
```

Then, I have WrapperLibrary/Sources/Clibndi/module.modulemap that looks like:

```
module Clibndi {
  header "/Library/NDI SDK for Apple/include/Processing.NDI.Lib.h"
  link "ndi_ios"
  export *
}
```

Finally, my application target (part of an Xcode project, not a Swift package) depends on WrapperLibrary, and I had to add "/Library/NDI SDK for Apple/lib/iOS" (including the quotation marks) to "Library Search Paths" in the "Build Settings" tab.

As an alternative to modifying the application target build settings, you could add a pkg-config file to a directory in your pkg-config search paths. For example, /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libndi_ios.pc:

```
NDI_SDK_ROOT=/Library/NDI\ SDK\ for\ Apple

Name: NDI SDK for iOS
Description: The NDI SDK for iOS
Version: 5.1.1
Cflags: -I${NDI_SDK_ROOT}/include
Libs: -L${NDI_SDK_ROOT}/lib/iOS -lndi_ios
```

Then use `.systemLibrary(name: "Clibndi", pkgconfig: "libndi_ios")` in your package manifest. I found this less convenient for users than just adding the setting to my application target, however.

Ideally you could add the NDI SDK's dependency library and frameworks to the pkg-config file as well (`Libs: -L${NDI_SDK_ROOT}/lib/iOS -lndi_ios -lc++ -framework Accelerate -framework VideoToolbox`), but it appears there is a bug in Swift's pkg-config parsing of `-framework` arguments, so I filed a bug: [SR-15933](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15933).

Answer (score 5):

Binary targets need to specified with `.binary_target`. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages) and example [here](https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement/blob/main/Package.swift#L83).

An example of a static library wrapped in an `.xcframework` looks like this from the file command:

```
$ file GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement
GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [arm_v7:current ar archive] [arm64]
GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement (for architecture armv7):  current ar archive
GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement (for architecture arm64):  current ar archive
```

One way to create the `.xcframework` file is to use Firebase's [ZipBuilder](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/ReleaseTooling) that creates a `.xcframework` files from static libraries that are specified with a CocoaPods podspec file.

Comment: `.binary_target` in SPM requires that the library is an XCFramework or an artifact bundle, and as I wrote above, that’s not possible in this case

Comment: Hmm, I'm not following. An `.xcframework` is just a directory structure that wraps `.framework`s. My understanding is that any `.framework` could be converted to an `.xcframework`.

Comment: First, I don’t have a .framework library but .a static library. Second, I tried creating an XCFramework using `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` as in [Apple Documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev544efab96), but you can’t create an XCFramework from a library that supports multiple platforms like `libndi_advanced_ios.a`: XCFramework only bundles binaries that are compiled for a single platform, and since the library is closed-source, I cannot recompile it to be compatible with XCFramework.

Comment: A static framework is a directory structure containing a static library and headers.  It should be possible go create a static framework from a static library with file system commands and then to create an xcframework from a framework with additional file system commands.

Comment: I tried implementing your solution but I got a "No such module 'NDI_iOS'" error when importing as a local XCFramework. This is a known issue ([1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651069)) although they marked as solved in [Xcode 13.2 (77465707)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_2-release-notes). I get the same issue when importing binary via URL. You can find implementation at [alessionossa/swift-ndi in the dedicated branch](https://github.com/alessionossa/swift-ndi/tree/custom-xcf). Therefore this is not a working solution.

Comment: It may help to compare against the directory structures of the xcframeworks referenced by https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement which are created via scripts with file management commands.

Comment: The XCFrameworks you linked bundle`.framework` libraries, while in my case the XCFramework wraps `.a` libraries. Therefore I think the two cases are not comparable.

Comment: My example includes archive libraries as well. When, a `.a` is bundled into a `.framework`, the `.a` is dropped from its name.  If you run the file command, you'll see they're both `:current ar archive`. I'll update the answer with more detail.

Comment: So you are suggesting to wrap a `.a` static library in a `.framework` and then in a `.xcframewok`, right? If so, is there any simple way to wrap a `.a` static library in a `.framework` (like when wrapping `.a` in `.xcframework`, it’s just a command)?  
I am a bit hesitant about this solution because XCFramework should support (theoretically) `.a` static libraries directly.

Comment: Yes. I'll add another update to the answer with one way to do it.